# Django errors in admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So currently, I'm trying to load a page in my Django admin and it gives me around 3 different errors (using sentry.io to track the errors)

> TypeError hasattr(): attribute name must be string
>
> FieldDoesNotExist BestOfListing has no field named
> 'articles.BestOfListing.id'
>
> KeyError <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>

The code is pretty complex and has been working completely fine, I recently updated from Django 2.0 to 2.1 (series of updates) and it started giving all these errors..
BestOfListing has no field named 'articles.BestOfListing.id'.. this in particular is a weird one because we dont have a primary key in this model and django just has the auto primary field so don't know why that's happening. Not sure where to even look?

Comment: Please show model definition.